# Finding "real" changes over time in logs

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I often am processing raw log files that contain various fields as well as a DateTime that they were changed. I would like a generic way to take these logs and for a specified subset of the columns, keep only the entries associated with an "actual" change in one of the specified columns. I would like this to generically accept many different possible combinations of class types for the selected columns.

1. Is there a built in / better way to do this?
2. If not, could I get feedback on my proposed way to do this?

e.g. the way I would like to use it is:

```
IEnumerable<SomeObjectWithManyProperties> rawLogs = getRawData();

var rowsToKeep = rawLogs.Select(x => new Tuple<int, int>(x.a, x.b))
                        .FindChanges();
```

Here is the code I have:

```
public class TimeStampedLog<T> 
{
    public DateTime TimeStamp;
    public T Log;

    public TimeStampedLog(DateTime timeStamp, T log)
    {
        TimeStamp = timeStamp;
        Log = log;
    } 
}

public static class Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Takes a list of objects with an associated Time for each object. 
    /// Returns the list of objects which reflect changes in the value
    /// of the object compared to the TimeStampedLog immediately prior to
    /// it in time.
    /// </summary>
    public static List<TimeStampedLog<T>> 
         FindChanges<T>(this IEnumerable<TimeStampedLog<T>> input)
    {
        var outputList = new List<TimeStampedLog<T>>();

        T prevEntry = default(T);

        // Sort the entries by their dates (ascending order
        foreach (var entry in input.OrderBy(x => x.TimeStamp))
        {
            //if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(entry.Log, prevEntry))
            if (!entry.Log.Equals(prevEntry))
            {
                outputList.Add(entry);
            }
            prevEntry = entry.Log;
        }

        return outputList;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you considered using LogParser2?

Comment: I you accept that the first evaluated item is always an "actual" change I don't see how you could improve your approach. Maybe you're after a LINQ-ish solution, but LINQ is not the right tool for this kind of "memoized" sequential processing.